# Difference between "scenery" and "landscape"

Tags: differences, nouns

What's the difference between *scenery* and *landscape*? In what situations can I use them interchangeably?

> The **scenery/landscape** at the school is beautiful.

Does *landscape* sound natural in the sentence above?

Comment: You should select a correct answer, 3 of them have 2 votes. If we haven't answered what you're looking for, please comment

Answer (score 4):

***Scenery*** is a term with generally broader in meaning than ***landscape*** (which may encompass ***landscape***).  It often refers to indoor settings.

Merriam-Websters defines ***scenery*** as:

1: the painted scenes or hangings and accessories used on a theater stage

2: a picturesque view or landscape

3: one's usual surroundings [e.g.] *needed a change of scenery*

***Landscape*** is generally much more focused on natural geography (although it may be humanly enhanced or supplemente):

1 a: a picture representing a view of natural inland scenery

b: the art of depicting such scenery

2 a: the landforms of a region in the aggregate

b: a portion of territory that can be viewed at one time from one place

c: a particular area of activity : scene [e.g.] *the political landscape*

Except for the third aspect of the second definition, which is somewhat metaphorical, the depiction reflects a natural place.

Answer (score 3):

Scenery and landscape are very different. Landscape has a geographical connotation. It describes the structure of the land and its shape. Scenery describes what is *on* the land, like trees, greenery, etc.

Also, there are some some cases where landscape is a countable noun. Scenery is always uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

You would not use *landscape* in that way; the user [asymptotically](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75448/difference-between-scenery-and-landscape/75454#75454) has explained why in an earlier answer.

What you could say, though is:

> *The **landscaping** at the school is beautiful*.

NOAD explains it like this:

> **landscape** (n.):  all the visible features of an area of countryside or land, often considered in terms of their aesthetic appeal.
>   **landscape** (trans. v.):  improve the aesthetic appearance of (a piece of land) by changing its contours, adding ornamental features, or planting trees and shrubs; [as n.] (**landscaping**)

So, if you want to point out that the landscapers have done a particularly good job of arranging the shrubs and caring for the flowers, then you could indeed say that *the school has beautiful landscaping*.  (In fact, in that context, I believe *landscaping* is a better word than *scenery*.)

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically speaking, the only difference is that *scenery* is uncountable whereas *landscape* can be countable or uncountable.

---

> Landscape comprises the visible features of an area of land, including **the physical elements of landforms**... **Human elements including different forms of land use**, buildings and structures..

*Landscape* refers to the **natural or man-made** features and **geographical structure** of an area of land.

On the other hand, *scenery* refers to the **general appearance** (which is merely what we're looking at without trying to analyze anything) or a **view** of a an area of land.

---

> A scene can describe a **portion** of a landscape.
>
> Landscape: An **expanse** of scenery.

Therefore, *landscape* is more likely to be used when talking about large areas whereas *scenery* would be properly used when talking about a relatively small area restricted to what can fit within one's range of vision.

---

Since *scenery* is, almost, always used when referring to **picturesque views** and never collocated with negative adjectives or used in an unfavourable context, I assume its most proper use would be when speaking from a *subjective* perspective.
*Landscape*, on the contrary, is more of a *technical* term, that can be used both subjectively or objectively.

---

So to answer your question, yes, they can be used interchangeably, but they don't convey the *exact* same meaning moving from a context to another.

Answer (score 1):

Grammar aside, here are some interesting points to consider:

**scenery**: the natural features of an area, such as mountains, valleys, rivers and forests, especially when these are attractive to look at (Oxford Learner’s Thesaurus 2008), cf. *mountain/coastal scenery*. That's why we usually talk about the lunar landscape and not scenery.

**landscape**: the land and features that you see around you in the countryside, or in the city (Longman Activator). The Oxford Learner's Thesaurus adds, "when you look across a large area of land." Note that while scenery is natural, a landscape can be artificially created/designed/altered, cf. *landscape architecture, urban landscape*, or *unspoiled landscape*.

*Scenery* is always nice (lovely, picturesque, gorgeous, fantastic, spectacular, or magnificent), whereas *a landscape* can be barren, bleak, harsh, or desolate.

The authors of the Longman Dictionary of English Language and Culture (2005) say the following:

> **Scenery** [U] is the general appearance of part of the country, considered from the point of view of beauty: *We passed through some beautiful scenery on our journey through the Lake District.*
>
> **A landscape** [C] is any combination of hills, valleys, fields etc, seen in a particular area: *The landscape was typical of the Lake District, with high mountains, lakes, and deep valleys.*