# What is the difference between “scenery” and “view”?

Tags: synonyms

Sometime I find a sentence and then I confused what is the difference between "scenery" and "view" because both of that word have same meaning.

Comment: If you imagine trees and fields in a valley, the trees and fields **are** the *scenery*. However, a *view* is what you can see from a particular location, and it will be different depending on which side of the valley you are standing.

Comment: Related: [Difference between “scenery” and “landscape”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75448/difference-between-scenery-and-landscape).

Answer (score 3):

The view is the experience had by viewers. The scenery is what the viewer is viewing. It is the actual stuff that makes up the view, the plants, buildings, sky and so forth. The view is the picture that this scenery gives a viewer from some particular vantage point.

Answer (score 2):

The view and the scenery are almost entirely separate ideas. For example, you could live in a location with beautiful scenery (a Rain Forest, a picturesque valley, etc) but have a terrible view (large tree completely blocking your window), while you could have an incredible view (large glass windows, nothing blocking them, clear sight lines) of horrible scenery (for example, a Waste Disposal yard).

Answer (score 1):

Generally they are very similar, however, while you can say "The view from my house is beautiful." you cannot say "The scenery from my house is beautiful."
So while the two words may be used to describe the same place, view is that place seen from a prticular vantagepoint.

Comment: While it is more usual to say that the view is beautiful, you could conceivably say that the scenery is beautiful.